# Accessing a template variable without it passing through it's widget

Tags: php, time, widget, modx

I'm try to ascertain an event time from a date template variable in a modx snippet. However that template variable has a date formatter widget in it which, while nicely formatting the date, doesn't output the time of the event.

I know that modx stores dates in unixtime in it's database, is there an easy way to directly access the unixtime of the event? I'm currently using `$modx->getTemplateVarOutput()` calls.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I just did a quick test and created a date template variable and after inspecting it in the database it is actually stored as the value "13-08-2010 12:56:00" and not as unixtime.

Comment: @Fishcake - That's interesting, and not what I expected! getTemplateVars() outputs the unixtime so must do an internal conversion, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out if you use `$modx->getTemplateVars()` instead then that allows access to the underlying unixtime in the 'value' element in each element.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the default format for the Data Formatter widget you'll see it's set at:

%A %d, %B %Y

Using the info [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) you would need a format similar to **%A %d, %B %Y %R** if you wanted to include time.

Comment: That would be the ideal but other part of the site rely of it being in it's current form